# Changing PDF Producer property with iText

Tags: java, itext

Is it possible to change an existing property of a PDF document with iText?

I tried this

```
Map<String, String> moreInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
moreInfo.put(Meta.PRODUCER, "XXX");
moreInfo.put(Meta.AUTHOR, "YYY");

try {
    stamp1.setMoreInfo(moreInfo);
}
catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), t.getMessage());
}
```

I don't get any exception, but also nothing changes.

Comment: Were you able to change the PDF Producer field. I am also getting the same problem. Please suggest.

Comment: The Author of iText and founder of iText Group Bruno Lowagie answers here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36351733/6584021 for a similar question.

Answer (score 5):

That's not possible with the [AGPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.html) version of iText. Buying a license will enable you to change that field. See AGPL version of iText limitations [here](https://itextpdf.com/en/taxonomy/term/4736).